# How can I temporary pause a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying write somwthing like messenger with built-in stegonagraphy. Idea is simple: when I send a text it switch it to images, when find a specified pixel in my program. But I have a problem with multithreading mechanism. I worte two methods: receive and write. They are working with excahnging some different commands. Also receive is in separated thread, so I can listen forever. But commands, that should intercept send method are intercepted by recieve method and nothing is happen. My idea is to temporary pause "receive" until I send all, that I need. This is my code for client (server also have same methods):

Client's side code:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext
import threading
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import time

HOST = '192.168.1.11' #my ip
PORT = 1234
SEPARATOR = '<SEPARATOR>'
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        self.gui_done = False
        self.running = True

        self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        self.receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        self.gui_thread.start()
        self.receive_thread.start();

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.title('Client 2')
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")

        self.chat_label = Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = Text(self.win, height=5)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.send_button = Button(self.win, text="Send", command=self.write)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)
        self.win.mainloop()


    def write(self):
        self.receive_thread.pause();
        for i in range(0,4):
            #---------Send command---------
            print('Connected...')
            time.sleep(0.1);
            self.sock.sendall('send'.encode());

            #---------Read file------------
            filename = (str(i+1) + '.jpg')
            if i==3:
                filename = 'end.jpg'
            data = None

            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                data = f.read()

            #--------Beginning sending process--------------
            while True:
                cmd = self.sock.recv(32).decode();

                if cmd:
                    print(cmd);

                #---------Receiving sendok-----
                if cmd == "sendok":
                    self.sock.sendall('finfo'.encode());
                    temp = (str(filename) +'<SEPARATOR>' + '%16d' % len(data)).encode();
                    print(temp);
                    self.sock.sendall(temp);

                #--------Receiving finfok------
                if cmd == "finfok":
                    self.sock.sendall('img'.encode());
                    self.sock.sendall(data)
                    print('File transmission done.')
                    break

        self.sock.sendall('end'.encode());
        self.receive_thread.start(self.sock);

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while True:
            print('[cmd] Waiting for command...')
            command = self.sock.recv(32).decode()
            if command:
                print('[cmd] ' + command)

            if command == 'send':
                command = None
                self.sock.sendall(b'sendok')

            if command == 'finfo':
                command = None
                finfo = self.sock.recv(1024).decode()
                print(finfo)
                if SEPARATOR not in finfo:
                    self.sock.sendall(b'finfo_error')
                    break
                else:
                    filename, filesize = finfo.split(SEPARATOR)
                    filesize = int(filesize)
                self.sock.sendall(b'finfok')

            if command == 'img':
                command = None
                print('[img] File name: ' + filename + ' | File size: ' + str(filesize) + '.')
                file = open(filename, 'wb')
                recvd = b''
                while filesize > len(recvd):
                    data = self.sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    recvd += data
                    file.write(data)
                    print('[rcv] Received ' + str(len(recvd)) + '/' + str(filesize) + '.')

            if command == 'end':
                command = None


client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

Server's code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import threading
import socket
import time

HOST_IP = '192.168.1.11'
HOST_PORT = 1234
SEPARATOR = '<SEPARATOR>'
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
NUMS_OF_CLIENT = 1

class Server:

    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        self.gui_thread.start()

        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.client_info = None
        self.socket_client = None

        self.socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket_server.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.socket_server.listen(NUMS_OF_CLIENT)
        print('[*] Waiting for client to connect')
        self.socket_client, self.client_info = self.socket_server.accept()
        print('[+] Client (' + str(self.client_info[0]) + ') connected.')

        self.receive_thread.start(self.socket_client);
        self.gui_done = False

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        gui_thread.start()

        self.running = True

    def receive(self):
        while True:
            print('[cmd] Waiting for command...')
            command = self.socket_client.recv(32).decode()

            if command:
                print('[cmd] ' + command)

            if command == 'send':
                command = None
                self.socket_client.sendall(b'sendok')

            if command == 'finfo':
                command = None
                finfo = self.socket_client.recv(1024).decode()
                if SEPARATOR not in finfo:
                    self.socket_client.sendall(b'finfo_error')
                    break
                else:
                    filename, filesize = finfo.split(SEPARATOR)
                    filesize = int(filesize)
                self.socket_client.sendall(b'finfok')

            if command == 'img':
                command = None
                print('[img] File name: ' + filename + ' | File size: ' + str(filesize) + '.')
                file = open(filename, 'wb')
                recvd = b''
                while filesize > len(recvd):
                    data = self.socket_client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    recvd += data
                    file.write(data)
                    print('[rcv] Received ' + str(len(recvd)) + '/' + str(filesize) + '.')

            if command == 'end':
                command = None

            command = None

    def send(self):
        self.receive_thread.pause();
        for i in range(6,10):
            #---------Send command---------
            print('Connected...')
            time.sleep(0.1);
            self.socket_client.sendall('send'.encode());

            #---------Read file------------
            filename = (str(i+1) + '.jpg')
            if i==3:
                filename = 'end.jpg'
            data = None

            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                data = f.read()

            #--------Beginning sending process--------------
            while True:
                cmd = self.socket_client.recv(32).decode();

                if cmd:
                    print(cmd);

                #---------Receiving sendok-----
                if cmd == "sendok":
                    self.socket_client.sendall('finfo'.encode());
                    temp = (str(filename) +'<SEPARATOR>' + '%16d' % len(data)).encode();
                    print(temp);
                    self.socket_client.sendall(temp);

                #--------Receiving finfok------
                if cmd == "finfok":
                    self.socket_client.sendall('img'.encode());
                    self.socket_client.sendall(data)
                    print('File transmission done.')
                    break

        self.sock.sendall('end'.encode());
        self.receive_thread.start(self.sock);


    def send_th(self):
        send_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.send)
        send_thread.start()
##        self.receive_thread.

    def exit(self):
        print('[*] Disconnecting...')
        try:
            self.socket_client.close()
            self.socket_server.close()
        except:
            self.socket_server.close()
        finally:
            print('[-] Disconnected111111.')
        print('[-] Disconnected.')

    def gui_loop(self):
        self.win = Tk();
        self.win.title("Client 1.0");
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray");

        self.chat_label = Label(self.win, text="Chat:", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        self.text_area = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = Label(self.win, text="Message:", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        self.input_area = Text(self.win, height=5)
        self.input_area.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3)

        self.start_button = Button(self.win, text="Host")
        self.start_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.start_button.grid(row = 8, column = 0)

        self.send_button = Button(self.win, text="Send", command = self.send_th)
        self.send_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.send_button.grid(row = 8, column = 1)

        self.exit_button = Button(self.win, text="Exit", command = self.exit)
        self.exit_button.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.exit_button.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")
        self.win.mainloop()


server = Server(HOST_IP, HOST_PORT)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, I can share server code if you want. But the main accent is on the threads. This is main problem